# Sending mails using PHP results in empty body content

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send mails using PHP.

For some reason when I receive the mail it doesn't contain a body on gmail (although it does contain the subject).

If I send the mail to my own mail on my own domain the mail has body content.

I use Zimbra mailserver on my own domain.

The message content is:

```
 --PHP-alt-31f1966d3bca8227c696f4123ec98b34
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

message body

--PHP-alt-31f1966d3bca8227c696f4123ec98b34
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>message body</p>


--PHP-alt-31f1966d3bca8227c696f4123ec98b34
```

The headers:

```
From: "Some user" <user@example.com>
Reply-To: "Some user" <user@example.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-31f1966d3bca8227c696f4123ec98b34"
```

The code:

```
$mail_send = @mail($to, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->headers);
```

Any idea what the reason could be for the missing body content?

Comment: Can you post the entire raw source of the email that was received? Maybe it's being modified somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last delimiter needs to end with an additional --. That may solve it.